# Intermittent connection failures with heroku postgres while using play-slick

Tags: postgresql, scala, heroku, playframework, slick

I have a play app on heroku connecting to a postgres instance with play-slick. Around 30% of the time when I deploy a new application I get this in my logs:

```
java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: db - Connection is not available, request timed out after 1007ms.
```

When I restart the application it will usually start again, though sometimes it takes a few tries.

Any advice for what I can do to debug this?

Comment: `Connection is not available,` how is your connection terminating? Sounds really intermittent to me.

Comment: It isn't terminating in the middle of running, its just never connecting on new deploys.

Comment: Might be a bit late but was there an earlier error in your logs on startup saying `Default transaction isolation level detection failed. (This ResultSet is closed.)`? I found I was getting the `Connection is not available` error but further down the stack trace was `Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unsupported transaction isolation level '-1'` so I set it manually (slick.dbs.default.db.isolation = "SERIALIZABLE") in `application.conf` and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, there is a period of time where both the old app and the new app are trying to get connections to the database, which means you have *double* you max allowed connections active.

There are two solutions:

- Upgrade your database plan to allow for more connection
- Reduce your max db connections by half

[play-slick uses HikariCP](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/PlaySlickAdvancedTopics#Connection-Pool) to pool connections, so you can probably configure your max connections with `maximumPoolSize`.

Comment: This was my first thought, but my maximum connections size is 120 connections and I never see myself going above ~45

Comment: Each database has two to three dynos connecting to it, one uses 3-4 connections, the other one or two use ~20 each.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've figured out what the issue was. I used the default heroku play Procfile which contains `-Ddb.default.url=${DATABASE_URL}` and additionally had the slick db url specified in my conf. Removing the former solved the problem.